# Update DOM element with specified data

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm using DOM to create element and my question is how 
I create path like below

```
FieldType Abstract="false" Name="New Entity0" m:HasStream="false"
```

I have created tag with `<FieldType>` but I don't know how to proceed 
with the `Abstract="false"` and  `Name="New field"` etc .

the code is:

```
 Element fld = document.createElement("FieldType");
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Next, you would simply do:

```
fId.setAttribute("Abstract", "false");
fId.setAttribute("Name", "New Entity0");
```

See the [element javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) for more information.

Make sure you don't forget append the element to the document when you're done!

Answer (score -1):

Example

```
L_div = document.createElement("div");
L_div.id="div_emp_detl";
L_div.className="cls_div_header";
document.body.appendChild(L_div);
```

For your case

```
fld.name = "New Entity";
fld.Abstract="false"
```